# How to 'split' a string with multiple commas not to be used as separator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following string :

```
'<http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&_order=asc,desc&_page=1&_limit=5>; rel="first", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&&_order=asc,desc&_page=2&_limit=5>; rel="next", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&&_order=asc,desc&_page=4&_limit=5>; rel="last"'
```

I would like to convert it into an array:

```
item 0 : <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&_order=asc,desc&_page=1&_limit=5>; rel="first", 

item 1 : <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&&_order=asc,desc&_page=2&_limit=5>; rel="next", 

item 2 : <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&&_order=asc,desc&_page=4&_limit=5>; rel="last"
```

I cannot use the comma as a separator, and if I try to use a substring 
( like

how can I proceed ? 
thanks for feedback

Comment: You could split at a comma followed by a whitespace

Comment: or perhaps even better, a comma followed by a whitespace and `<` as this might be less prone to false matches.  Will need some string manipulation after.

Comment: If you feel brave enough, you can also use a regex

Comment: Why do you have a string in such a hard-to-parse format in the first place?

Comment: As long as you don't have to rely on it, use e.g. `urls.split(/, (?=<http)/)`

Comment: Why are you specifically asking about ES6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the url are encoded and don't contain any spaces the simplest approach would be:

```
urls.split(/, /)
```

If all url protocols are `http` (and already suggested on comments):

```
urls.split(/, (?=<http)/)
```

```js
const urls = '<http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&_order=asc,desc&_page=1&_limit=5>; rel="first", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&&_order=asc,desc&_page=2&_limit=5>; rel="next", <http://localhost:8080/api/users?_sort=lastName,firstName&&_order=asc,desc&_page=4&_limit=5>; rel="last"';

const spaceUrls = urls.split(/, /);
const httpUrls = urls.split(/, (?=<http)/);

console.log('Using space:', spaceUrls);
console.log('Using protocol:', httpUrls);

// test both results
spaceUrls.map((url, index) => {console.log(`Is spaceUrls[${index}] the same as httpUrls[${index}]? ${url === httpUrls[index]}`)})
```

Comment: thanks a lot !  urls.split(/, (?=<http)/) is what I was looking for !, could not find  a good link to using split() like that ...